# Sync 3rd party API to SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api2

I want to pull data from a 3rd party API and push it into a SQL table.

Is it a good idea to create a Web API 2 project in ASP.NET to pull data from another API and run CRON job to pull data periodically?

Please suggest the best possible solution.

Thanks!

Comment: We don't know anything about your requirements, environment etc. How could we know what's the best possible solution?

Comment: @JamesZ, Requirement is to pull data from a 3rd party API which give a response in JSON then I want to parse JSON response and add to SQL Server Database.
Environment, ASP.NET C# 
Is it a good idea to create a Web API project and do it or background job using window service to sync data from an API to SQL table.

Comment: The question is too broad for this site.